# Docker toolbox on windows 10. Bind for 0.0.0.0:8081 failed: port is already allocated error

Tags: docker-compose

I have setup docker toolbox on windows 10. While building the project I encountered the following error :- Bind for 0.0.0.0:8081 failed: port is already allocated ? The sudo service docker restart command isn't working. Please provide me a solution for the same.

Comment: some other service running on your port 8081?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you need to stop running the current container.  For that you are going to know current CONTAINER ID:

```
$ docker container ls
```

You get something like:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
97a32e8928ef        friendlyhello       "python app.py"     51 seconds ago      Up 50 seconds       0.0.0.0:4000->80/tcp   romantic_tesla
```

Then you stop the container by:

```
$ docker stop 97a32e8928ef
```

Finally, you try to do what you wanted to do, for example:

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

Answer (score 1):

Commonly if this error happens, I restarting my winnat with commands:

```
$ net stop winnat

// build your project

$ net start winnat
```

---

If that doesnt help. I restart whole docker with commands:

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
```

Then docker offers to restart docker-service.